# Simultaneous recursion and iteration

Tags: matlab, logic

I have a function `f(data)` which takes a matrix as input and outputs two matrices say `n1` and `n2`. When they are combined it gives the original matrix.

I have to iterate this say `m` times such that at iteration 1 the `data` matrix is passed. At the next iteration I have `n1` and `n2` and now I have to call `f(n1)` and `f(n2)`.
In the next iteration the op of `f(n1)` say `n11` and `n12`, as well as op of `f(n2)` say `n21` and `n22` are my result now they have to be called as `f(n11)`, `f(12)`, `f(n21)`, and `f(n22)`. This process continues till m iterations. So that I will have `2^m` matrices as my final result.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDIT: OP has stated the language is matlab after this answer was written. My code sample will remain c-style as I don't know matlab.)

This is hard to do without knowing which language this is in. Your function should carry two paremeters: matrix and iteration. So that inside each operation, you reduce the iteration count by one:

```
f(inputMatrix, iteration)
{
    //Stop condition
    if (iteration <= 0)
        return; (no change)
    //...
    f(n1, iteration-1);
    f(n2, iteration-1);
}
```

Using recursive functions, you must always take care of controlling when your function must stop. Check for the iteration count and other conditions (matrix can be split, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the help @MPelletier...its in matlab btw !!